# How to flatten a QuantumCircuit object to a single QuantumRegister and ClassicalRegister form in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, transpile

In Qiskit, I am looking for a convenient way to "strip-off" a `QuantumCircuit` object from its multiple `QuantumRegister` and `ClassicalRegister` objects, such that in the final `QuantumCircuit` object there will be only 1 `QuantumRegister` and 1 `ClassicalRegister`, without any loss of the circuit's qubits, bits or content.

I haven't found any built-in option in Qiskit for this feature so far. However, when I look at a job page in IBM Quantum website I see a QASM code of the job's circuit exactly as I am looking for (with 1 qreg and 1 creg). So I infer there is a convenient way to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way from the top of my head is to simply compose your multiregistered circuit to a flat one:

Say you have this circuit:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister

qreg1 = QuantumRegister(1, 'qreg1')
qreg2 = QuantumRegister(1, 'qreg2')
creg1 = ClassicalRegister(1, 'creg1')
creg2 = ClassicalRegister(1, 'creg2')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg1, qreg2, creg1, creg2)
circuit.h(qreg1)
circuit.cx(qreg1, qreg2)
circuit.measure(qreg1, creg1)
circuit.measure(qreg2, creg2)
circuit.draw()
```

```
         ┌───┐     ┌─┐   
  qreg1: ┤ H ├──■──┤M├───
         └───┘┌─┴─┐└╥┘┌─┐
  qreg2: ─────┤ X ├─╫─┤M├
              └───┘ ║ └╥┘
creg1: 1/═══════════╩══╬═
                    0  ║ 
creg2: 1/══════════════╩═
                       0
```

You can compose it to a flat one like this, resulting in a circuit like the one you are searching for:

```python
flat_circuit = QuantumCircuit(circuit.num_qubits, circuit.num_clbits)
flat_circuit.compose(circuit, inplace=True)
flat_circuit.draw()
```

```
     ┌───┐     ┌─┐   
q_0: ┤ H ├──■──┤M├───
     └───┘┌─┴─┐└╥┘┌─┐
q_1: ─────┤ X ├─╫─┤M├
          └───┘ ║ └╥┘
c: 2/═══════════╩══╩═
                0  1
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. However I wonder if this method can be computationally costly when dealing with large circuits.

Comment: the code in `QuantumCircuit.compose` iterates on `other.data` and copy it. So yes. It is not O(1).